# Multiple inheritance - Child class problem in randomly choosing a method

Tags: python, random

My code should make the `Parrot` class randomly choose only one method of speaking, what the code currently does is repeat all the lines at the same time.

- Current output

```
This is my ninja way!
Hi, I am Goku!
Give me your strength Pegasus!
None
```

- Code

```
import random

class Naruto():
    def talk1(self):
        print("This is my ninja way!")

class Goku():
    def talk2(self):
        print("Hi, I am Goku!")

class Seiya():
    def talk3(self):
        print("Give me your strength Pegasus!")

class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        print(random.choice((super().talk1(), super().talk2(), super().talk3())))

parrot = Parrot()
parrot.repeat()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you call all methods in the `choice()` call.
Choose the method first, and then call it.

```py
class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        print(random.choice((super().talk1, super().talk2, super().talk3))())
```

Also this method will always print `None` after the call, since your methods do not return anyting. So maybe that's closer to what you want:

```py
class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        random.choice((super().talk1, super().talk2, super().talk3))()
```

And since `Parrot` inherits from the superclasses without the methods being overridden, you can just access it on the instance.

```py
class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        random.choice((self.talk1, self.talk2, self.talk3))()
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `super`, as `Parrot` didn't *override* any of the inherited methods. But you also need to choose a method first, *then* call the chosen method.

```
class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        m = random.choice([self.talk1,
                           self.talk2,
                           self.talk3]
                         )
        m()
```

If all *three* parent classes had defined `talk` differently, you could do something like

```
class Parrot(Naruto, Goku, Seiya):
    def repeat(self):
        cls = random.choice([Parrot, Naruto, Goku])
        super(cls, self).talk()
```

Comment: Another good solution, thanks.